# Use eigenvectors and eigenvalues for transformation matrix of quadractic form.

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, quadratic-forms, symmetric-matrices

I'm really confused by a task I have been given:

We are looking at a quadratic form $Q(\vec{x})=\vec{x}^TA\vec{x}$ where the symmetric matrix $A = A^T$ has normalized eigenvectors $\vec{v_i}$ with corresponding eigenvalues $\alpha_i$. So far, I understand every component. But then we are asked to use $\vec{v_i}$ and $\alpha_i$ to compute new coordinates $x_i^{\prime}=B_{ij}x_j$ (with an orthogonal change of basis $B$) and coefficients $\lambda_i$ such that $Q^{\prime}(\vec{x})^{\prime}= \lambda_1 x_1^{\prime}+...+\lambda_n x_n^{\prime}$ with $Q(\vec{x})=Q^{\prime}(\vec{x})^{\prime}$.

Even though I know about the quadratic form as well as about the eigenvalue problem, I really can't figure out whats being asked in this task. I'd appreciate and help or hint.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by a "normed eigenvector". Perhaps you mean that the eigenvector is "normalized", i.e. chosen to have a norm (length) of $1$.

Comment: Yes, I mean of length one, its my wrong translation from a different language

Comment: Ok that makes sense, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the main idea: if $[x]_{\mathcal B} = (x_1',\dots,x_n')$ denotes the [coordinate-vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinate_vector) of $x = (x_1,\dots,x_n)$ relative to the basis $\mathcal B = \{v_1,\dots,v_n\}$ (which is to say that $x = x_1' v_1 + \cdots + x_n' v_n$), then we have
$$
Q(x) = Q'(x') = \alpha_1^2x_1' + \cdots + \alpha_n^2 x_n'.
$$
Accordingly, answer the question by finding an orthogonal matrix $B$ for which $x_i' = \sum_j B_{ij}x_j$, where $x_i'$ denotes the $i$th entry of $[x]_{\mathcal B}$ as defined above.

---

Regarding the solution: we want a matrix $B$ for which $[x]_{\mathcal B} = Bx$.  Let $M$ denote the matrix whose columns are $v_1,\dots,v_n$. We find that this matrix solves the "opposite" problem. In particular, it's easy to show that we have $M[x]_{\mathcal B} = x$.

If we solve for $[x]_{\mathcal B}$, we see that $[x]_{\mathcal B} = M^{-1}x$. However, because $M$ is orthogonal (has orthonormal columns), it's easy to find the inverse of $M$; we have $M^{-1} = M^T$, the transpose of $M$.

Long story short: $B$ is the matrix whose rows are $v_1,\dots,v_n$.

Comment: First of all, thanks for your answer. Ok so the vector $\vec{x}^{\prime}$ has been "written" in a basis that is not the standard basis, in which $\vec{x}$ has been written. That non-standard basis happens to be composed of eigenvectors of the matrix $A$. But what do I gain from that?

Comment: @MJP What you gain is an easier way to use $Q$. It's much easier to apply/analyze the function $Q(x) = \lambda_1 x_1^2 + \cdots + \lambda_n x_n^2$ than it is to (directly) analyze $Q(x) = x^TAx$.

Comment: So am I looking for B through $$ \vec{x}'^T B\vec{x}' = Q'(x') = \alpha_1^2x_1' + ... + \alpha_n^2 x_n^' $$ ? Sorry for bad understanding.

Comment: @MJP No, $B$ is not the matrix of the quadratic form relative to this new basis; it is simply the change-of-basis matrix. We just want $\vec{x'} = B\vec x$.

Comment: If you want the matrix $D$ for which $Q'(\vec{x'}) = (\vec{x'})^TD\vec{x'}$, that would be the diagonal matrix
$$
D = \pmatrix{\alpha_1 \\ & \ddots \\ && \alpha_n}.
$$

Comment: Ok, but $D$ won't help me find $B$. I don't think I'll make it through this today, but I'll try again, tomorrow. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: @MJP That's correct, and no problem. A quick hint: although the reason we're finding $B$ has to do with our quadratic form, actually finding $B$ has nothing to do with the quadratic form or eigenvalues and eigenvectors. The only important piece of information here is that $\{v_1,\dots,v_n\}$ is an orthonormal basis of $\Bbb R^n$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108559/discussion-between-mjp-and-omnomnomnom).

Comment: See my latest edit.